# Sequelize validate not working on save()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model with a validation like this:

```
validate: {
    isEmail: {msg: 'This field must be an E-Mail!'}
}
```

It's working when I use `.create()` method but not working when I use `.update()`/`.save()` methods. What did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To validate the instance you can call `.validate()` on the model instance as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that unchanged fields was not validated by sequelize. I was trying without changing value of field so couldn't get validation error.